# Mantener valor de variable automática entre llamadas a la función

Tags: c, variables, function, variables-globales, codeblocks

Cada vez que llamo a la función `takeMoney( )`, la variable `total` se *resetea* al valor que está indicado en el código (`500`).

¿ Como puedo hacer que esa variable mantenga el último valor asignado ? ¿ Tengo que usar punteros ?

```
int options(){
  printf("1.Take money\n2.Acccount overview\n3.Last movs\n4.Exit\nSelect an option:");
}

void takeMoney(int amount){
  int total=500;
  total=total-amount;
  printf("Left money: %d\n",total);
}

int main(){
  int money,num;
  num=0;
  while (num !=1 || num !=2 || num !=3 || num!=4){
    options();
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if (num == 1){
      printf("how much money?\n");
      scanf("%d",&money);
      takeMoney(money);
      options();}
  }
}
```

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español o de lo contrario puede terminar cerrada

Comment: No queda claro cual es la duda ni cual es el resultado que querés lograr? Que total se mantenga? Por favor edita la pregunta.

Comment: Exacto Magus. Mi idea es que total se matenga con su valor original y a medida que llame a la funcion takeMoney descuente de ese total

Comment: Declara e inicializa `total` en `main()` no en `takemoney()`.

Comment: y debes hacer que `takemoney()` pase por referencia este valor.

Comment: Por favor, **no obligues** a la gente a leerse los comentarios para entender tu pregunta. [Edítala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/341678/edit) para que tenga sentido e incluir la información que te pidan. Los comentarios pueden ser eliminados en cualquier momento: **no forman parte de la pregunta**. Solo deberían usarse para solicitar información adicional.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿ Como puedo hacer que esa variable mantenga el último valor asignado ?

Tienes que guardar la variable fuera de la función, por ejemplo puedes declararla en `main`:

```
void takeMoney(int amount, int *total)
{
  *total -= amount;
  printf("Left money: %d\n",*total);
}

int main()
{
  int total = 500;
  takeMoney(100, &total);
  takeMoney(150, &total);
}
```

> ¿ Tengo que usar punteros ?

No necesariamente, también puedes usar el `return` para devolver el valor de la variable:

```
int takeMoney(int amount, int total)
{
  total -= amount;
  printf("Left money: %d\n",total);
  return total;
}

int main()
{
  int total = 500;
  total = takeMoney(100, total);
  total = takeMoney(150, total);
}
```